# JSON Hardcoded Data C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm creating the JSON Data Manually in C#. I need to return the Array of JSON Results. I want to return the array as like below, but i dont want to get Fruits Text.

```html
public JsonResult GetFruits()
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                Fruits = new List<object>
                {
                    new {
                            Color="Red",
                            Name="Apple",
                            Shape="Round"
                        }
                }
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

It's displaying the json result like below:

```
    {
    "Fruits": [
        {
            "Color": "Red",
            "Name": "Apple",
            "Shape": "Round"
        }
    ]
}
```

but what I really want is:

```
[
        {
            "Color": "Red",
            "Name": "Apple",
            "Shape": "Round"
        }
]
```

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: @Balaji then why do you have a `Fruits` property if you do not want it in your JSON output?

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult GetFruits()
        {
            return Json(
                new List<object>
                {
                    new 
                    {
                        Color="Red",
                        Name="Apple",
                        Shape="Round"
                    }
                }, 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But ! IMHO you should create a class `Fruit` with Color, Name, Shape props, and then use it like this :

```
public JsonResult GetFruits()
{
    var fruits = new List<Fruit>
    {
        new Fruit 
        {
            Color = "Red",
            Name = "Apple",
            Shape = "Round"
        },
        new Fruit 
        {
            Color = "Green",
            Name = "Melon",
            Shape = "Square"
        }
    };

    return Json(fruits, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@JimmyFL already provided the answer.

I found out the different way of doing it

```
 public JsonResult GetFruits()
    {
        return Json(new List<object>
        {
            new {
                    Color="Red",
                    Name="Apple",
                    Shape="Round"
                }
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[Screen shot of the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIMNK.jpg)